# ISC-DHCP-SERVER IPV6

Tags: debian, ip, server, networking

Tengo un servidor Debian y quiero usarlo como servidor DHCP, con ipv4 funciona sin problemas, pero mi configuración para ipv6 no funciona correctamente, los clientes obtienen la ipv4 asignada por el servidor, pero no obtienen ninguna con ipv6.
[image: Configuración del servidor Debian]

aquí esta la configuración para ipv6
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo donde se habilita el ipv6

[image: Configuración de red]

y esta es la conexión de mi red.

Uso maquinas virtuales y en todas están sobre la misma interfaz de mi maquina física, esa interfaz tiene una conexión a un modem Arris, pero no esta conectado a internet, es solo una prueba local.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me da este tipo de ip y no la que yo le asigno.

Comment: Hola Osvaldo, ¿podrías colocar el código que tienes en la imagen como texto? Se necesita para poder reproducir el ejemplo.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes especificar versión de tu servidor? He comprobado los parámetros con `isp-dhcp-server 4.4.1-2`.

#### verificaciones

- No has hablado del fichero de configuración por defecto, cuyo especifica a que interficies de red va actuar dicho demoneo `dhcp`.  Verifica en `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`  que el parametro `INTERFACESv6=""` tenga alguna definida. De serlo asi reinicia el servico y prueba de nuevo.
- Prueba de arranque manual:

  Detiene el servidor si esta encendido `systemctl stop isc-dhcp-server.service`

  Ejecuta  `sudo /usr/sbin/dhcpd -6 -d -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcp6.conf eth0`. Sustituye eth0 por tu interficia. Vamos a ejecutar el demonio manualmente.

  Si hay algún problema de configuración aquí te saldrá.
- A veces el problema esta en que el fichero de `leases` de `v6` no existe. Puedes crearlo manualmente

  ```
  sudo touch /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd6.leases
  sudo chown dhcpd:dhcpd /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd6.leases
  ```

Cualquiera cosa edita y comenta y te ayudare con el proceso, a la vez que mejoramos pregunta y respuesta.

[Fuente de consulta](https://jochen.kirstaetter.name/dhcpv6-ipv6-in-your-local-network/)

Comment: Tengo la misma versión, pero no funciono.

Comment: Salió error durante la ejecucion manual?  systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service   sale runing?